# Is it wrong to use "lord" as part of a Facebook name?

Tags: practical-islam, naming, asma-ul-husna, aqidah

I have a friend whose Facebook name is "lord faisal".  I tried to convince him that this was wrong, but he disagreed with me saying that there are many meanings of the term "lord".

Now, I asked him to consult an Alim, but he seems to disagree to the fact for all sake that this is nothing of an issue.  He told me that he gave himself this title being inspired from "Game of Thrones".  (I don't really know what this is as I don't watch movies or serials.  But if it is wrong, please inform me.)

Can you suggest what I should do? Am I correct in thinking that using "lord" as part of the name is not right?

Comment: I think you might be equating the word 'lord' with 'Rabb'? But 'lord' in the English language can mean several things depending on its context.

Comment: http://quran.com/4/36

Answer (score 3):

I think you are not right on this, because the word "lord" does not necessarily point to God (Allah) in English. Lord can mean "a man of noble rank or high office" according to the definition that google provides for it. On the other hand "our Lord" or "the Lord" is and has traditionally been the way to address God in Christianity and should not be used for in one's name.

On the other hand, it is against humbleness to use such a word in your name and it is better not to do so.

Comment: Lord XYZ (with a capital L) is the proper English way of writing the name of someone with that rank.  The capital L does not imply God.

Comment: thanks , yes , I got it . since he didn't use the capital letter , so it didn't traditionally mean the Creator , thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context. The Arabic translation for lord is `رب - Rab` which means more of `The Owner of Something`  instead of God.

For example, if you look in the Quran, the word Rab:

> قَالَ يَا قَوْمِ لَيْسَ بِي ضَلَالَةٌ وَلَـٰكِنِّي رَسُولٌ مِّن رَّبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ
>
> قُلْ إِنَّ صَلَاتِي وَنُسُكِي وَمَحْيَايَ وَمَمَاتِي لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ
>
> الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ

You can see that the context is giving to Allah as he is the Lord of Everything. The Quran in another spot mentions it in a different context with Prophet Yuspeh:

> وراودته التي هو في بيتها عن نفسه وغلقت الأبواب وقالت هيت لك قال معاذ الله انه ربي أحسن مثواي [12:23]
>
> She tried to seduce him, she who he is in her house and she closed the doors and said "come to me". He said I seek refuge from Allah, he is my lord who has given me shelter and taken care of me.

In another instance in the same Surah:

> ياصاحبي السجن أما أحدكما فيسقي ربه خمرا
>
> Oh my jailmates, one of you will serve his lord wine

The prophet PBUH mentioned in many hadiths the context of the lord of the house, lord of the animals, etc..:

> وفي الصحيحين وغيرهما أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال في ضالة الإبل: دعها، فإن معها حذاءها وسقاءها ترد الماء وتأكل الشجر حتى يجدها ربها
>
> In both of the Saheheen, the prophet said on a lost Camel: Leave her until her lord finds her.

Finally, in the context the person is writing it "lord faisal" it is similar to master faisal which should be ok (its more of a title). Saying "lord of faisal", then it would be forbidden (unless he is a slave).

Comment: thanks , I got it , yes , he didn't use Lord , rather he only used lord , the small letter to his title . So , in that context , I am not right , 
And I have addressed this issue and came into good terms with telling him that yes , it is not a problem to use it , though I added that , it is better not to use it . :)

Comment: @NajmusSakib It does not matter if its a lowercase or uppercase l. All that matter is the context as explained above.

Answer (score -1):

It is disliked in Islam to give yourself titles. We are all servants of Allah. Yet if there is nothing more important of his faults than this, then do proceed with finding the reason of this naming if his intention is aligned as 'American Muslim says, then its OK. Generally I don't recommend you going after your friend only for this small minor issue.
Yet, have in mind that Faisal is more humble of a name than Lord Faisal. Definitely Sadiq is more humble of a name than 'Lord Sadiq'.

Comment: His intention is this : 
he went on to give this title because of what he calls "GAME OF THRONES " he got inspiration from this something . I don't know actually what it is . But I know this much , people are a fan of this so called game of thrones .
he told me that he gave this title because he was inspired from this "game of thrones "

Comment: @NajmusSakib
I suggest that you educate (rather than instructing) him with reason once or twice only. If he isn't willing to listen then leave it be لا اکراه فی الدین!
The more you insist the more it worsens. Sometimes it doesn't happen right away, it will happen in 6 mths/ 2,5 years.

btw watching Game of thrones could be more of a problem than that of their naming. [Game of thrones parental guide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/parentalguide)

I suggest that you just drop this issue for now and simply socialize with him for his more important faults to simply make him more God-fearing

Comment: thanks brother , this information has been a real help . When I give dawah to people , Alhamdulillah , I avoid extremism , forcing, and try to address the issues with love and care , and good reasoning . 
Jazakallahu khair , brother Vazir.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to change the title ,some ppl have names like malik but if there is some thing which have doubt so according to hadith we should leave the thing with doubt and it could be makrooh ,,one must be cautious in every part of life in facebook or anything